# Separating variables from formula

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a simple command to seperate a formula i have saved as text to columns.
code example:

```
print(fo)
"count_new ~ sno + winter_dummy + spring_dummy+ autumn_dummy "
```

EDIT
this is the output example I am looking for

```
iner<- c("hour","dewp","humid","wind_dir","wind_speed")
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate on what you mean by "separate a formula". What are you expecting as output?

Comment: You may want to check the library `insight` and functions like `find_predictors` (even when they apply to a model object, but not a formula)

Comment: Maybe: `trimws(unlist(strsplit(fo, "[~+]")))`

Comment: Why `fo` and `iner` do not match? Can you show your expected output based on `fo` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
get_vars <- function(x) { 
  x <- strsplit(x, " |~|\\+|\\*")[[1]]; 
  as.list(x[nzchar(x)][-1])
}
```

So that you can do

```r
get_vars(fo)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "sno"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "winter_dummy"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "spring_dummy"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "autumn_dummy"
```

Comment: Thanks! this may work but I need it as a list, and without the main variable

Comment: @Stat.Enthus see my update. Is that what you mean? You say you want the output as a list, so that's what I have done. However, in your question you show that you want a vector, which is what I had initially. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple way using the method `terms.formula`.

```
rhs <- function(x){
  if(!inherits(x, "formula")) x <- as.formula(x)
  attr(terms(x), "term.labels")
}

fo <- "count_new ~ sno + winter_dummy + spring_dummy+ autumn_dummy "
rhs(fo)
#[1] "sno"          "winter_dummy" "spring_dummy" "autumn_dummy"
```

Answer (score 0):

In a short form:

```
fo <- "count_new ~ sno + winter_dummy + spring_dummy+ autumn_dummy "

labels(terms(as.formula(fo)))
#> [1] "sno"          "winter_dummy" "spring_dummy" "autumn_dummy"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>